# Повторная инсталяция при запуске приложения

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windowsinstaller

Создал приложение, прикрутил к нему стандартный Visual Studio Installer, с помощью него создаю msi инсталятор. Установка проходил как положено, но если запустить под другим пользователем это приложение, то оно требует указать инсталяционный файл. Кто-нибудь встречался с такой проблемой? Как это исправить?
*к сожалению проверял только на Windows 10, возможно на более старых версиях всё хорошо работает.